# Where to store instance of API object in react (next.js) app?

Tags: reactjs, api, state

I'm trying to build react (with next.js) based chat client using the LiveChat CustomerSDK [API](https://developers.livechat.com/docs/extending-chat-widget/customer-sdk#using-the-api).
I currently use a *useEffect* hook to initialize and then store the object with a *useState* hook.

```js
const [customerSDK, setCustomerSDK] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    const sdk = CustomerSDK.init(config);
    setCustomerSDK(sdk)
}, []);
```

But I am wondering whether *useState* is the best way for the `customerSDK` object, since it doesn't need to trigger a re-render. Therefore I also considered using *useRef* instead or maybe just storing it in the `window` object. But neither "feels right".

I have to consider that I need to access the customerSDK object to set the listeners (e.g. `customerSDK.on('connected', ...`) and also for example sending messages (`customerSDK.sendEvent(...`)

Is there a recommended/preferred way to approach a situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

Theres another option if you know you only have 1 project accessing it, simply put it in a file and export it, then import this everywhere you need it. If it needs no context (i.e. react state) from your components, why have it stored in a component at all?

```
const sdk = CustomerSDK.init(config);
export default sdk
```

Then import that where you need it. It will act as a singleton.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not to work for me. I get this error *ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined*, when I run `CustomerSDK.init(config)` outside of `useEffect`. Seems to be an issue with Next.js (see https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/huqw55/nextjs_native_websockets_not_defined/)

Comment: Ah yeh I see. You need this to run only on client and next blurs the lines. In a pure react app, it would be ok. I'd probably  initialise this in a ref and pass that down a react context in that case.

Comment: Would this would a way to accomplish your approach? [react-singleton-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-singleton-hook)

Comment: Yep! I think so, thats a neat solution actually -- thanks for posting; I could do with this in my own app.